# object-private Vs class-private

Tags: ruby, oop, private, encapsulation, smalltalk

Is there a notion of **object-private** in any OOP language ?? I mean more restrictive than the classic **private** access ?

[Private (or class-private) restricts the access to the class itself. Only methods that are part of the same class can access private members.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_science))

**object-private :** restricts the access to the object itself. Only methods objects that can access members and it will be impossible to write :

```
public class Person {

private String secret;
public String othersSecret;

public void snoop(Person p) {
    othersSecret = p.secret; //will be prohibited by the compiler
}
```

**EDIT :**

If it exist can you give me some examples ... if not do you think it's interesting to have this kind of feature ??  and is it possible to simulate it in others OOP languages ??

**EDIT 2 :**
Thanks you guys, all the answers were very instructive ...

Until now, the temporary **conclusion** :

The [instance-private](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_science)) notion exists in 2 languages :

**1 - Smalltalk** after hours of googling :) I found the language behind this concept !!

[The state an object holds is always private to that object. Other objects can query or change that state only by sending requests (messages) to the object to do so.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk)

**2 - Ruby** thanks to *Logan* :

[One person summed up the distinctions by saying that in C++, “private” means “private to this class”, while in Ruby it means “private to this instance”. What this means, in C++ from code in class A, you can access any private method for any other object of type A. In Ruby, you can not: you can only access private methods for your instance of object, and not for any other object instance (of class A).](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes)

Comment: I just edited my post to be more clear ... I ask about theory ... in any OOP language ...

Comment: one of the things that made me go 'huh?' over C#, AFAIK it only supports class private.

Comment: @Johannes : 'class-private' is the normal way that OOP langages (C#, java ... ) handles encapsulation ... until now i only see Ruby (thanks to Logan) who permit the 'object-private' ...

Comment: @wj: feel free to stick Smalltalk in your own answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not

Comment: @outis: thx for the tip ! i do not know it was possible/recommanded to answer our own questions ... will do it next time ;)

Comment: If you have Smalltalk, you can also add `Self` and `Strongtalk` and `Newspeak` and all its other descendants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby, per-object private is the only private (you have to use `protected` to get class private behavior).

E.g. foo.rb:

```
 class A
    private
    def a=(x)
            @a=x
    end
    public
    def a
            @a
    end

    def b(c)
            c.a = 2
    end
 end

 a1 = A.new
 a2 = A.new
 a1.b(a2)
```

Running it, we get

```
 foo.rb:12:in `b': private method `a=' called for #<A:0xb7c9b6e0> (NoMethodError)
    from foo.rb:18
```

Of course there are ways around this, but there almost always are.

Comment: Very interesting example !! I'm wondering if there's other languages that support this ... and why it's not the standard in others OOP languages ...

Comment: There are all sorts of OO features that only show up in some languages. See CLOS for some interesting ones (e.g. multimethods, metaclasses and method combination (e.g. :before, :after and :around), of which the latter two prefigured aspect-oriented programming).

Comment: @outis: what I like most in CLOS is the linearization of calls in multiple inheritance when we use call-next-method ... big up to CLOS ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think the feature you want could be implemented by, figuratively, not allowing Persons to communicate directly.
To achieve this with minimal effort you can introduce an interface, which would not provide access to things you want to make secret.

```
public interface IPerson
{
    void communicateFormally();
}

public class Person : IPerson 
{
    private String secret;
    public String othersSecret;

    public void snoop(IPerson p) {
      othersSecret = p.secret; //will be prohibited by the compiler
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, this could be "hacked" by an ugly cast, but I think that's the problem of the one hacking.

Comment: but this will give us a "pivate-interface" feature ... not really a "private-object" like "Logan Capaldo" ruby example ...

Answer (score 2):

After hours of googling :) I found the language behind this concept : **Smalltalk**

[The state an object holds is always private to that object. Other objects can query or change that state only by sending requests (messages) to the object to do so.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk)

Comment: See pdf "Encapsulation and Inheritance in Object-Orlented Programming Languages" http://eprints.kfupm.edu.sa/37524/1/37524.pdf

Comment: See "Design Principles Behind Smalltalk"  http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/smalltalk.html

Comment: The "Encapsulation and Inheritance" link is dead. It appears to be a reference to this paper: Snyder, Alan. _Encapsulation and Inheritance in Object-Oriented Programming Languages_. ACM SIGPLAN Notices V21 N11, June 1986. [Link](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/960112.28702). The ACM is moving toward open access, and the full text is available directly from that link to the ACM site.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, which is what it looks like you are writing, "private" means class-private. There is no way to force object-private mode. The reason for this is that "private" is a way of enforcing *encapsulation*, not *security*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this kind of distinction of class vs object `private` exists for the most common languages OO such as C#, C++, Python, Java, Objective-C ... To be fair I can't remember of a language that actually has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create objects in Java containing instance variables that other instances of that interface cannot see. Trivial example:

```
class Secretive { }
Secretive s = new Secretive() {
    int unknowable = 42;
};
Secretive t = new Secretive() {
    String unfathomable = "banana";
};
```

Comment: This is not exactly true.  In your example, you create two new anonymous classes, and create one instance of each.  So each instance can have data that is private to its (anonymous) class, but that's not exactly the same thing as having data private to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Person
    {
        private String privateSecret;
        public String PublicInformation;

        public void Snoop(Person p)
        {
            // will be allowed by the .NET compiler
            p.PublicInformation = p.privateSecret;
        }
    }
```

just use *properties*, or *readonly* fields to enforce your *security*.

You can use also **internal** accessor to incapsulate your class in a assambley.

You can also use some Deny techniques like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk3b9142.aspx).

Comment: it also will be allowed by javac and all oop compiller i know ... I ask if there is a language who offer an other level of encapsulation that prohibit this ...

Comment: @Paolo : It's not "bizarre" it's the normal way that OOP langages handle encapsulation ... that's why I asked my question :)